# LegendEntries, Range, PieChart, Delete, Condition

Tags: vba, range, conditional-statements, legend, pie-chart

I've been trying to find the mistake or what I'm doing wrong for a few days. I show here the current output and what it should be. I think maybe I'm defining the range with some mistake, or maybe `LegendEntries(i)`, doesn't work with the same index as `Points(i)`. Any suggestion ? Or maybe how could I do this from another approach ?

The thing here is to get a chart and delete the legend and labels associated with "0" values.

The First graphic is my current output.
The second one is my desire output, and what I expected to get with my code.

The Legends that have 0 values are "Asia" and "Latam", but my current output is throwing "Latam" and it should throw "RoW", because "RoW" insn't associated with 0 values, its value is "5.0%".

```
Sub CreateChart()
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).ChartObjects.Delete

    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim rowi As Integer
    Dim MyRange As Range


rowi = Range("I7").Row ' Index to select last row non empty, in this example it's row number 11.
Do While Sheets(1).Cells(rowi, Range("I7").Column).Value = _
IsEmpty(Cells(rowi, Range("I7").Column))
rowi = rowi + 1
Loop

'----------------------------------------------------CHART---------------------------------------------------------------

Set MyRange = Range("I6:M6" & ",I" & rowi & ":M" & rowi)

Set MyChart = Sheets(1).Shapes.AddChart(xlPie).Chart

     MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=MyRange

With MyChart.SeriesCollection(1)
 .HasDataLabels = True
 .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
End With

With MyChart
 .HasLegend = True
End With

For i = 1 To (Range("M6").Column - Range("I6").Column + 1)

If  Cells(rowi, Range("I6").Column + i - 1).Value = 0 Then
MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Delete
MyChart.Legend.LegendEntries(i).Delete
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

[image: Current Output]

[image: Desire Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomás, Here you go. The problem you were having is that each time you deleted one of the legend entries from the `LegendEntries` object, the index numbers of the remaining entries all shift down 1 to fill the hole. So after you deleted index 3 (Asia), index 4 became 3, 5 became 4, and so on... To solve the problem I just stepped backwards through the index numbers, thus ensuring that the deletions would not effect the order of things to come.

```
 Sub CreateChart()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(1).ChartObjects.Delete
        Dim MyChart As Chart
        Dim rowi As Integer
        Dim MyRange As Range
    rowi = Range("I7").Row ' Index to select last row non empty, in this example it's row number 11.
    Do While Sheets(1).Cells(rowi, Range("I7").Column).Value = _
        IsEmpty(Cells(rowi, Range("I7").Column))
        rowi = rowi + 1
    Loop

    '----------------------------------------------------CHART---------------------------------------------------------------

    Set MyRange = Range("I6:M6" & ",I" & rowi & ":M" & rowi)

    Set MyChart = Sheets(1).Shapes.AddChart(xlPie).Chart
         MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=MyRange

    With MyChart.SeriesCollection(1)
     .HasDataLabels = True
     .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    End With
    MyChart.HasLegend = True

    For i = (Range("M6").Column - Range("I6").Column + 1) To 1 Step -1 ' <---CHANGED THIS
        If Cells(rowi, Range("I6").Column + i - 1).Value = 0 Then
            MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Delete
            MyChart.Legend.LegendEntries(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this helps, should you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Genius !! Many Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear it Tomas! Good luck with the rest of your project.